# Which repeater item did I just affect?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

Suppose a repeater created 10 instances of the template below. Then the user clicked on the`btnRemove` control in the 3rd instance.

How would I be able to access that item set specifically in the repeater?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptItems" runat="server" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="lightShadowBox gradientGray">
                <label class="labelSmallInline">Description: </label>
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Description") %>
                <label>Path:</label>
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Path") %>
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnRemove" OnClick="click" Text="Remove" CssClass="standardButton"/> 
            </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the btton's `NamingContainer` property to get the `RepeaterItem`, then you can use `item.FindControl` to get the reference to the other controls.

```
protected void click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btnRemove = (Button) sender;
    RepeaterItem item = (RepeaterItem) btnRemove.NamingContainer;
    // for example:
    Label labelSmallInline = (Label) item.FindControl("labelSmallInline");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of a `Repeater` exactly like a loop, it will iterate through all the data and display it.  Which makes it incredibly easy to custom build a web-page while it pulls data out of the data source.

Your primary issue, *how do you identify which item is which from the repeater*?  The answer, the `id` the unique identifier.  As the `Repeater` iterates it is also exposing the unique identifier or `id`.

So you would want to do something like this:

```
<a href="Page.aspx?id=<%# Eval("Id") %></a>
```

Now you could at page load, call `Page.Request.QueryString[@"Id"]` which would provide a value to ensure you delete the proper item.

Your other approach is called instantiation:

```
protected void btnRemove(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var item = (((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument;
}
```

Which can now expose those `Eval` that expose the id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.command(v=vs.110).aspx) event of the Button control to capture the data from posted row.

**FYI:** You can just use `Eval("")` instead of `DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "")`

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptItems" runat="server" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="lightShadowBox gradientGray">
            <label class="labelSmallInline">Description: </label>
            <%# Eval("Description") %>
            <label>Path:</label>
            <%# Eval("Path") %>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnRemove"
                OnCommand="btnRemove_Command"
                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Path") %>'
                Text="Remove" CssClass="standardButton"/> 
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

protected void btnRemove_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    string path = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your event handler of the btnRemove button you can get the sender object from the handler and try to fetch this sender belongs to which item of the 10.

```
protected void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
var btnRemove = sender as Button;

//Now you can search the repeater for the control or if I can recall correctly you can get the 
//Parent property of the button and traverse from there
}
```